# Twillio Whatsapp sender api, messages out of order

Tags: python, rest, twilio, whatsapp

I'm building a whatsapp chatbot that uses the twillio integration with whatsapp, the application is a REST API in python that is configured trough the whatsapp senders tab on the twillio website.
All the responses from the API are xml strings with the following template.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Response>
            <Message>
                <Body>
                   Example Message
                </Body>
            </Message>
        </Response>
```

The problem is that when I send multiple messages using multiple message and body tags they are not displayed in the correct order I sent.

Is it a problem in my end? Or is this somewhat unavoidable?

Comment: where is the python code ? => [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the async nature of message delivery, it's not possible to guarantee the order. You can circumvent that, if you implement your own event queue on your backend and make sure to hold the `send()` call of the next message until the previous one has been [delivered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/track-outbound-message-status).

```py
@app.route("/message-status", methods=['POST'])
def incoming_sms():
    message_sid = request.values.get('MessageSid', None)
    message_status = request.values.get('MessageStatus', None)
    logging.info('SID: {}, Status: {}'.format(message_sid, message_status))

    return ('', 204)
```

For more details, please refer to this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/guarantee-sms-and-mms-delivery-order-in-csharp-dotnet).

Comment: I don't see how that would help with the problem to be honest, all the messages are sent in one response containing multiple message and body tags. I can't check if the previous message was already sent and only then send the next one

Comment: You actually can check the status of the previous message when you use the [status callbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/outbound-message-status-in-status-callbacks). The snippet above shows how you can handle the response of that callback.

Comment: The code uses the webhook API, should I still use the queue system and the twillio client api to send the messages? Right now I just return one large xml

Comment: Yes, this is something you would need to change in your implementation. With TwiML-only, you, unfortunately, won't get where you need to be.

Comment: I changed the implementation and am currently using the twilio sdk in python to send messages asynchronously, I have a class responsible for handling this process, but while following the example in the github README my application runs into an error: 

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'AnyIO worker thread'

Comment: This seems like a different question now. Please open a new question and share as many details and code samples as possible.